# Is it possible to *map* my Windows' desktop as my home desktop?

Tags: windows, mount, home-directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I integrate my Windows filesystem with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178284/how-do-i-integrate-my-windows-filesystem-with-ubuntu)

I am using Windows and Ubuntu, is it possible to *map* Windows' desktop as my home desktop (symlink or something like this?)?